# only one out of 3 datanodes gets started in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have one master and three slave cluster. NO Virtual environment. Its all in in network.
after I do start-dfs.sh in Namenode, I see that NameNode and one of the datanode starts properly.
But other two datanodes gives the following exception (except for change in the ip address in the log). Only one out of three datanodes work at any time.

After stopping and starting clusters, I see that at any given time, only one slave (datanode) is running. but what is running seem random. sometime I have slave 1, sometime slave 2 and sometime slave 3 running.

I am not totally clear what is wrong here. but I see an unregisteredNodeException coming up in the log files of the datanodoes that fail to start

Here is the error message:

```
2014-06-26 13:00:54,866 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50075
2014-06-26 13:00:54,870 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2014-06-26 13:00:54,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source DataNode registered.
2014-06-26 13:00:54,893 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2014-06-26 13:00:54,894 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort50020 registered.
2014-06-26 13:00:54,894 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort50020 registered.
2014-06-26 13:00:54,896 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dnRegistration = DatanodeRegistration(dig14.baker:50010, storageID=DS-1161815082-172.16.30.208-50010-1403746077641, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020)
2014-06-26 13:00:54,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Finished generating blocks being written report for 1 volumes in 0 seconds
2014-06-26 13:00:54,910 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.UnregisteredDatanodeException: Data node 172.16.130.214:50010 is attempting to report storage ID DS-1161815082-172.16.30.208-50010-1403746077641. Node 172.16.130.213:50010 is expected to serve this storage.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:5049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.processBlocksBeingWrittenReport(FSNamesystem.java:3869)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.blocksBeingWrittenReport(NameNode.java:1109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)
```

Here is my `core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
 <value>hdfs://dig11:10001</value>
<!-- <value>hdfs://localhost:10001</value> -->
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/scratch/USERS/sridhar/hadoop</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using shared storage like nfs? Are you by any chance using dhcp addresses where each node's IP could change? Or did you register a single IP address? I have a lot of followup questions based on your answers.

Comment: I think I am using shared storage, but I have a scratch partition that is dedicated to the each of the slave nodes I work with. I mean there is two partition; one is shared storage and one is dedicated storage. I work on dedicated storage partition. They have non-changeable IP address. They are static

Comment: The error message you posted clearly shows that one datanode is presenting the other datanode's data as its own. That is clearly the issue. Each datanode should have their own exclusive area in the shared storage that the other nodes can't use.

Comment: I have this partition called `scratch` which is not shared across any nodes. I set-up `hdfs` inside this partition. so I don't see any shared storage for datanodes here.

Comment: Did you try to copy some files from one node to another by any chance? Otherwise, you might want to file a bug against hadoop.

Comment: well I copied configuration files across nodes, but my `hadoop/conf/tmp` is empty anyway

Comment: Why is your data stored on a storage called `scratch`? Your data are not transient. They should be in persistent storage. Hopefully it is just a naming convention. Where do you store the actual data?

Comment: right now, I dont have any data. I want the cluster up and running. The only reason I use `scratch` is it is the local filesystem for that particular node. They are persistent. Actual data will stored in /scratch/hadoop/tmp

Comment: I have put my core-site.xml above which is same for all the master and slaves

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56387/discussion-between-brain-storm-and-alvits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on one datanode is being presented by another datanode and namenode is refusing it.

If it is a test environment and you are willing to lose any existing data in hdfs, you could cleanup the datanode directories and namenode directories and reformat DFS.

Remove all existing data in the `dfs.name.dir`, `dfs.namenode.name.dir`.

Finally reformat DFS with `hdfs namenode -format`